# Prohibit function call within other function at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, invoke

I want to prohibit that any `invocable/function` is called within a specific other function:

```
int foo()
{
    return 1;
}

template <typename... Args>
void specific(Args... t){}

specific(1); // OK
specific(foo()); // This should raise a compile error
```

`specific` should only get non-invocables, is this possible?
I don't see how to use [std::is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) for this.

A solution with a macro would also be fine, which C++14 at disposal.

EDIT: Background is that we want to prohibit function calls within logging statements(as macros):

```
auto a = something();
LOG_MSG("Log something {}", a); //OK

LOG_MSG("Log something {}", something()); // should not be possible
```

Comment: `specific(foo())` is indistinguishable from `auto x = foo(); specific(x)` from your function's point of view.

Comment: @Botje I think it would be equivalent to `auto x = foo(); specific(std::move(x));`, no?

Comment: @cdhowie Correct. The situation is slightly different still if `foo` returns a reference, but the main point stands.

Comment: `foo()` is non-invocable, but `foo` is., do you want to forbid `specific(foo)`?

Comment: In your example, `foo()` is not called within `specific()`.   It is called in context of the CALLER, and the value it returns is passed to `specific()`.

Comment: This feels very much like an XY problem